# How do i set up a remote desktop connections from Ubuntu 14.04 to a WIndows 7 dekstop?

Tags: 14.04, remote

i've looked at all the discussions i could find on this & haven't found one that gives sufficient information on how to set this up using Remmina. Just not sure what i'm doing & i need to connect to a Win7 machine at work to be able to work from home. i guess i'm looking for suggestions on where to find a 'how-to' on setting up the remote connection using Remmina.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with remmina, but you can try other programmes, if you just need a remote connection.
i.e. 
teamViewer (worked for me on windows xp-ubuntu 12.04).
Or 
nomachine: i tried version 3, and the version 4 is known to be buggy, but I never tried it on windows so you may be lucky.

Answer (score 0):

Remmina, NoMachine, or freerdp? Whatever!

Your requirement is to connect from home to your W7 computer at work.

Firstly you have to enable your W7 remote desktop to accept a connect from the Internet.

I'm sure you have a work router/hub with a firewall, so you have to enable a rule on that to allow the inbound connection from your home computer.You need a dedicated IP address for your home router/comp, work router and a dedicated internal IP address for your W7 comp.

When that's configured correctly, you can go home armed with your work router/hub IP Address and follow these instructions to setup  Remmina:-

http://www.7tutorials.com/connecting-windows-remote-desktop-ubuntu

Better still phone home to someone who can initiate the connection to test that it works

Answer (score 0):

In order to configure and setup remote desktop connection from Ubuntu to Windows remote desktop, Open up Windows 10 host and open the Remote Desktop Connection client. Use the search box to search for remote keyword and click on the Open button. Enter the Ubuntu's remote desktop share IP address or hostname. Optionally, allow the Windows 10 to save your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

In order to configure and setup remote desktop connection from Ubuntu to Windows remote desktop, Open up Windows 10 host and open the Remote Desktop Connection client.

Use the search box to search for remote keyword and click on the Open button.

Enter the Ubuntu's remote desktop share IP address or hostname. Optionally, allow the Windows 10 to save your credentials.

Comment: This answer seems incomplete. There are a lot of variables that need to be considered, such as corporate firewalls, VPNs, policies and the like. This solution *may* work if both devices are on the same local network, but will not specifically solve the problem.